# Unfortunately the application has stopped working in Android Emulator

Tags: java, android, select, contacts

When I try to run my application in emulator I get the error message `Unfortunately the application has stopped working`.

this is the database handler of the app

```
package com.nkannan.contactmanager;

import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;
import android.net.Uri;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;


public class DatabaseHandler extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;

    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "contactManager",
            TABLE_CONTACTS = "contacts",
            KEY_ID = "id",
            KEY_NAME = "name",
            KEY_PHONE = "phone",
            KEY_EMAIL = "email",
            KEY_ADDRESS = "address",
            KEY_IMAGEURI = "imageUri";

    public DatabaseHandler(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);

    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
      db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE" + TABLE_CONTACTS + "(" + KEY_ID + "INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT," + KEY_NAME + "TEXT," + KEY_PHONE + "TEXT," + KEY_EMAIL + "TEXT," + KEY_ADDRESS + "TEXT," + KEY_IMAGEURI + "TEXT)");

    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS" + TABLE_CONTACTS);

        onCreate(db);
    }


    public void createContact(Contact contact) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = getWritableDatabase();

        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();

        values.put(KEY_NAME, contact.getName());
        values.put(KEY_PHONE, contact.getPhone());
        values.put(KEY_EMAIL, contact.getEmail());
        values.put(KEY_ADDRESS, contact.getAddress());
        values.put(KEY_IMAGEURI, contact.get_imageUri().toString());

        db.insert(TABLE_CONTACTS, null, values);
    }

    public Contact getContact(int id) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = getReadableDatabase();

        Cursor cursor = db.query(TABLE_CONTACTS, new String[]{KEY_ID, KEY_NAME, KEY_PHONE, KEY_EMAIL, KEY_ADDRESS, KEY_IMAGEURI}, KEY_ID + "=?", new String[]{String.valueOf(id)}, null, null, null, null);

        if (cursor != null)
            cursor.moveToFirst();

        assert cursor != null;
        Contact contact = new Contact(Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(0)), cursor.getString(1), cursor.getString(2), cursor.getString(3), cursor.getString(4), Uri.parse(cursor.getString(5)));
        db.close();
        cursor.close();
        return contact;
    }


    public void deleteContact(Contact contact) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = getWritableDatabase();
        db.delete(TABLE_CONTACTS, KEY_ID + "=?", new String[]{String.valueOf(contact.getId())});
        db.close();
    }


    public int getContactsCount() {
        SQLiteDatabase db = getReadableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_CONTACTS, null);
        int count = cursor.getCount();
        db.close();
        cursor.close();

        return count;

    }

    public int updateContact(Contact contact) {

        SQLiteDatabase db = getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();

        values.put(KEY_NAME, contact.getName());
        values.put(KEY_PHONE, contact.getPhone());
        values.put(KEY_EMAIL, contact.getEmail());
        values.put(KEY_ADDRESS, contact.getAddress());
        values.put(KEY_IMAGEURI, contact.get_imageUri().toString());

        return db.update(TABLE_CONTACTS, values, KEY_ID + "=?", new String[]{String.valueOf(contact.getId())});
    }


    public List<Contact> getAllContacts(){

        List<Contact> contacts = new ArrayList<>();

        SQLiteDatabase db = getWritableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_CONTACTS, null);

        if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            do {
                Contact contact = new Contact(Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(0)), cursor.getString(1), cursor.getString(2), cursor.getString(3), cursor.getString(4), Uri.parse(cursor.getString(5)));
                contacts.add(contact);
            }
            while (cursor.moveToNext());

            cursor.close();
        }

        return contacts;
    }
}
```

// this is the main activity class

```
package com.nkannan.contactmanager;

import android.annotation.TargetApi;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Build;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.text.Editable;
import android.text.TextWatcher;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TabHost;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;


public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    EditText nameTxt, phoneTxt, emailTxt, addressTxt;
    ImageView contactImageImgView;
    List<Contact> Contacts = new ArrayList<>();
    ListView contactListView;
    Uri imageUri = Uri.parse("android.resource://com.nkannan.contactManager/drawable/no_images.jpg");
    DatabaseHandler dbHandler;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        nameTxt = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtName);
        phoneTxt = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtPhone);
        emailTxt = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtEmail);
        addressTxt = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtAddress);
        contactListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);
        contactImageImgView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imgViewContactImage);
        dbHandler = new DatabaseHandler(getApplicationContext());

        TabHost tabHost = (TabHost) findViewById(R.id.tabHost);

        tabHost.setup();

        TabHost.TabSpec tabSpec = tabHost.newTabSpec("creator");
        tabSpec.setContent(R.id.tabCreator);
        tabSpec.setIndicator("Creator");
        tabHost.addTab(tabSpec);

        tabSpec = tabHost.newTabSpec("list");
        tabSpec.setContent(R.id.tabContactList);
        tabSpec.setIndicator("List");
        tabHost.addTab(tabSpec);


        final Button addBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnAdd);
        addBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Contact contact = new Contact(dbHandler.getContactsCount(),String.valueOf(nameTxt.getText()),String.valueOf(phoneTxt.getText()),String.valueOf(emailTxt.getText()),String.valueOf(addressTxt.getText()),imageUri);
                dbHandler.createContact(contact);
                Contacts.add(contact);
                populateList();
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),nameTxt.getText().toString() + "Your Contact has been created",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });

        nameTxt.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

            }

            @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.GINGERBREAD)
            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

                addBtn.setEnabled(!nameTxt.getText().toString().trim().isEmpty());
            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

            }
        });

    contactImageImgView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()

    {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent intent = new Intent();
            intent.setType("image/*");
            intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
            startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Select Contact Image"), 1);
        }

    });

        List<Contact> addableContacts = dbHandler.getAllContacts();
        int contactCount = dbHandler.getContactsCount();

        for (int i = 0; i<contactCount; i++) {
            Contacts.add(addableContacts.get(i));
        }

        if (!addableContacts.isEmpty())
            populateList();
    }
   public void onActivityResult(int reqCode, int resCode, Intent data) {
       if (resCode == RESULT_OK) {
           if (reqCode == 1)
               imageUri = data.getData();
               contactImageImgView.setImageURI(data.getData());
       }

   }
    private void populateList(){
        ArrayAdapter<Contact> adapter = new ContactListAdapter();
        contactListView.setAdapter(adapter);
    }

    private class ContactListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Contact>{

        public ContactListAdapter(){
            super(MainActivity.this, R.layout.listview_item, Contacts);
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View view, ViewGroup parent){
            if (view == null)
                view = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.listview_item, parent,false);

            Contact currentContact = Contacts.get(position);

            TextView name = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.contactName);
            name.setText(currentContact.getName());
            TextView phone = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.phoneNumber);
            phone.setText(currentContact.getPhone());
            TextView email = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.emailAddress);
            email.setText(currentContact.getEmail());
            TextView address = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.cAddress);
            address.setText(currentContact.getAddress());
            ImageView ivContactImage = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.ivContactImage);
            ivContactImage.setImageURI(currentContact.get_imageUri());

            return view;

        }
    }
    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}


package com.nkannan.contactmanager;

import android.net.Uri;


public class Contact {

    private String _name,_phone,_email,_address;
    private Uri _imageUri;
    private int _id;

    public Contact (int id, String name, String phone, String email, String address, Uri imageUri){
        _id = id;
        _name = name;
        _phone = phone;
        _email = email;
        _address = address;
        _imageUri = imageUri;

    }

    public int getId(){return _id;}

    public String getName(){return _name;}

    public String getPhone(){return _phone;}

    public String getEmail(){return _email;}

    public String getAddress(){return _address;}

    public Uri get_imageUri() {return _imageUri;}
```

// logcat message

```
05-28 11:57:54.408    2446-2453/com.nkannan.contactmanager W/art﹕ Suspending all threads took: 5.103ms
05-28 11:57:54.513    2446-2446/com.nkannan.contactmanager E/SQLiteLog﹕ (1) no such table: contacts
05-28 11:57:54.514    2446-2446/com.nkannan.contactmanager D/AndroidRuntime﹕ Shutting down VM
    --------- beginning of crash
05-28 11:57:54.514    2446-2446/com.nkannan.contactmanager E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.nkannan.contactmanager, PID: 2446
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.nkannan.contactmanager/com.nkannan.contactmanager.MainActivity}: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such table: contacts (code 1): , while compiling: SELECT * FROM contacts
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2298)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2360)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:144)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1278)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5221)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:899)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694)
     Caused by: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such table: contacts (code 1): , while compiling: SELECT * FROM contacts
            at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativePrepareStatement(Native Method)
            at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.acquirePreparedStatement(SQLiteConnection.java:889)
            at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.prepare(SQLiteConnection.java:500)
            at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteSession.prepare(SQLiteSession.java:588)
            at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.<init>(SQLiteProgram.java:58)
            at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteQuery.<init>(SQLiteQuery.java:37)
            at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDirectCursorDriver.query(SQLiteDirectCursorDriver.java:44)
            at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.rawQueryWithFactory(SQLiteDatabase.java:1316)
            at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.rawQuery(SQLiteDatabase.java:1255)
            at com.nkannan.contactmanager.DatabaseHandler.getAllContacts(DatabaseHandler.java:115)
            at com.nkannan.contactmanager.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:109)
            at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5933)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1105)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2251)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2360)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:144)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1278)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5221)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:899)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694)
05-28 11:58:06.579    2446-2453/com.nkannan.contactmanager W/art﹕ Suspending all threads took: 171.174ms
05-28 11:58:19.382    2446-2453/com.nkannan.contactmanager W/art﹕ Suspending all threads took: 30.624ms
05-28 11:58:24.047    2446-2453/com.nkannan.contactmanager W/art﹕ Suspending all threads took: 5.010ms
```

The logcat error message says that 
`SQLiteException: no such table: contact (code 1): while compiling: SELECT * FROM contacts`

What can be the reason of this error?

Comment: obviously, do you have the table `contact` in your database?

Comment: Seems, your Contacts table is not created. I think, because both SQLs in `onCreate` and `onUpgrade` are written without any whitespaces. I wonder, why didn't you get SQLException before you event get into `getAllContacts`